# Returning results of a query against results of same query with a join

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to put this into words, hence the bad title;

I want to return the results of one query alongside the results of the same query inner joined to another table (so, total number of value1 against number of value1 that appears in the other table). So I want to return the count per owner of the following query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Owner), COUNT(Owner) FROM Actions
INNER JOIN [DataCapture].[dbo].DataCapture ON Actions.Contact_ID = DataCapture.ID 
GROUP BY Owner ORDER BY Owner
```

And then I want to find out the percentage from the total;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Owner), COUNT(Owner) FROM Actions 
GROUP BY Owner ORDER BY Owner
```

I thought INTERSECT or EXCEPT would be the way, but since I am returning distinct counts it doesn't work very well.

EDIT: For clarity, the results of the first and second queries are as follows respectively;

```
USER1   212
USER2   613
USER3   155
USER4   375
USER5   8
USER6   76



USER1     1218
USER2     849
USER3     237
USER4     1062
USER5     39
USER6     418
```

So what I want is, in 1 query, the results of the first query over the results of the second query to give me the percentage.

Comment: Still not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. Can you provide samples as input/output data?

Comment: Ill add the results of the 2 queries, 1 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a CTE (I guess you're working with Sql Server) or an inner query

```
select a.Owner, count(*), totalActions, (count(*) * 1.0 / totalActions) * 100 as yourpercentage
from Actions a
join DataCapture db on db.Id = a.Contact_Id
join (select Owner, count(*) as totalActions from Actions
      group by Owner) total on total.Owner = a.Owner
group by a.Owner, total.totalActions
```

No need of distinct with group by, by the way

Comment: Query doesn't run, total.totalActions is in the select but not the group by clause.

Comment: Yeah, had a where clause I didn't include in the original question, once I figured out it goes on twice this returned correctly :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       ACTIONS_BY_DATACAP.Owner AS OWNER, 
       (ACTIONS_BY_DATACAP.Cnt/TOT_ACTIONS_BY_USR.TotCnt)*100 AS PERCENTAGE 
FROM
(
 SELECT DISTINCT(Owner) as Owner, COUNT(Owner) as Cnt FROM Actions
 INNER JOIN [DataCapture].[dbo].DataCapture ON Actions.Contact_ID =  
 DataCapture.ID 
 GROUP BY Owner ORDER BY Owner
) AS ACTIONS_BY_DATACAP
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT(Owner), COUNT(Owner) as TotCnt FROM Actions 
GROUP BY Owner ORDER BY Owner
) AS TOT_ACTIONS_BY_USR
ON TOT_ACTIONS_BY_USR.Contact_ID =  
 ACTIONS_BY_DATACAP.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Will a CTE example get you what you want?

```
;WITH q1 as
(SELECT Owner, COUNT(Owner) c1 FROM Actions
INNER JOIN [DataCapture].[dbo].DataCapture ON Actions.Contact_ID = DataCapture.ID 
GROUP BY Owner),
q2 as
(SELECT Owner, COUNT(Owner) c2
FROM Actions 
GROUP BY Owner)

SELECT
     q1.Owner, q1.c1, q2.c2, q1.c1/q2.c2 percentage
FROM
    q1
JOIN
    q2 ON q1.Owner = q2.Owner
ORDER BY 
   Owner
```